# MAUI: Shell content navigation does not navigate to correct view

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui

Recently I started to migrate my Xamarin framework based application to MAUI framework. I have faced an issue where my `Appshell` doesn't navigate to the correct page when I press the content in flyout but it shows the last page navigated on the content page.

I have used same code on Xamarin and I didn't face this issue. Below I have attached a gif and code as well. I have a logic when application is started in `app.xaml.cs` where it sets `Mainpage` to `Appshell` if `autologin` is checked or login is successful else the main page will set to login page.

[image]

AppShell.xaml

```
     <Shell  x:Class="SnyderMobile.AppShell"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:SnyderMobile.Views"
            xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SnyderMobile.Controls"
            Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
            BackgroundColor="#FAFAFA"
            Shell.ForegroundColor="#5E5D5D"
            Shell.TitleColor="#5E5D5D">
    
        <Shell.FlyoutBackdrop>
            <LinearGradientBrush 
                StartPoint="0,0"
                EndPoint="1,1">
                <GradientStop 
                    Color="White"
                    Offset="0.1"/>
                <GradientStop 
                    Color="#E786A8"
                    Offset="0.6"/>
                <GradientStop 
                    Color="#BC1538"
                    Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Shell.FlyoutBackdrop>
    
        <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
            <Grid 
                BackgroundColor="Black">
                <Image 
                    Aspect="AspectFill" 
                    Source="background_shell.png" 
                    Opacity="0.6" />
                <StackLayout 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Frame 
                        HeightRequest="80" 
                        WidthRequest="80" 
                        CornerRadius="50" 
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center">
                        <Label 
                            Text="{Binding FirstLetter}" 
                            FontAttributes="Bold" 
                            FontSize="Large" 
                            TextColor="#BC1538" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                            Padding="0" 
                            Margin="0"/>
                    </Frame>
                    <StackLayout
                        Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Spacing="2">
                        <Label 
                            Text="{Binding Welcome}"
                            FontAttributes="Bold" 
                            FontSize="Large" 
                            TextColor="White" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                            VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <!--<Frame 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0"  
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                            HasShadow="False" 
                            HeightRequest="25" 
                            Padding="0" 
                            IsVisible="{Binding LocationIsVisible}">-->
                        <StackLayout 
                            Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                            IsVisible="{Binding LocationIsVisible}">
                            <Image 
                                Source="locate_icon_white" 
                                HeightRequest="25" 
                                Aspect="AspectFit" 
                                Margin="0" />
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding Location}"
                                FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                FontSize="Default" 
                                TextColor="White" 
                                VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <!--</Frame>-->
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    
        <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
            <controls:FlyoutFooter />
        </Shell.FlyoutFooter>
    
        <FlyoutItem 
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False" 
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
            <ShellContent 
                Title="Change Working Location" 
                Icon="navigation.png" 
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:LocationPage}" />
            <ShellContent 
                Title="Main Menu"
                Icon="home_grey.png" 
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:AboutPage}" />
            <!--<ShellContent 
                Title="Locate Tag" 
                Icon="locate_icon.png" 
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:LocateTag}" />
            <ShellContent 
                Title="Settings" 
                Icon="setting_grey.png" 
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:SettingsPage}"/>-->
            <!--<ShellContent Title="Main Menu" Icon="home_grey.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:AboutPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Settings" Icon="setting_grey.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:SettingsPage}"/>-->
        </FlyoutItem>
    
    </Shell>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs

```
        public partial class AppShell : Shell
        {
            private AppShellViewModel _viewModel;
            public Dictionary<string, Type> Routes { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        
            public AppShell()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                BindingContext = _viewModel = new AppShellViewModel();
                PropertyChanged += Shell_PropertyChanged;
            }
            private void Shell_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                _viewModel.UpdateShell(e);
            }
        }
```

AppShellViewModel.cs

```
        public class AppShellViewModel : BaseViewModel
        {
            private string _welcome;
            public string Welcome { get => _welcome;  set { _welcome = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Welcome)); } }
    
            private string _firstLetter;
            public string FirstLetter { get => _firstLetter; set { _firstLetter = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstLetter)); } }
    
            private string _location;
            public string Location { get => _location; set { _location = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Location)); } }
    
            private bool _locationIsVisible;
            public bool LocationIsVisible { get => _locationIsVisible ; set { _locationIsVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LocationIsVisible)); } }
            public AppShellViewModel()
            {
                Welcome = "Hello, " + "Test";
                FirstLetter = T;
    
            }
    
            public void UpdateShell(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.PropertyName.Equals("FlyoutIsPresented"))
                {
                    if (GlobalVariables.LoginAuth.Location != null)
                    {
                        LocationIsVisible = true;
                        Location = "Test";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

LocationViewModel.cs

```
    public class LocationViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        #region Properties
        private List<JsonLocation> _locations;
        public List<JsonLocation> Locations { get => _locations; set { _locations = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Locations)); } }
        private JsonLocation _location;
        public JsonLocation Location { get => _location; set { _location = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Location)); } }
        public ICommand Tapped_Command { get; set; }
        #endregion
    
    
        public LocationViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            Navigation = navigation;
            Title = "Working Locations";
            Tapped_Command = new Command(List_Tapped);
        }
    
        public async void List_Tapped()
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutPage());
        }
    }
```

App.xaml.cs (Mainpage logic)

```
    private async void SetMainPageAsync()
    {
        if (autoLogin)
        {
            try
            {
                var resp = CheckLogin(userName);
                if (resp.Success)
                {
                    MainPage = new AppShell();
                }
                else
                {
                    MainPage = new LoginPage();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MainPage = new LoginPage();
            }
    
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new LoginPage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug to check the executing steps when you click the flyoutitem?

Comment: I had insert breakpoints on AboutPage and LocationPage but when I click change location breakpoint on AboutPage gets triggered instead on LocationPage

Comment: @SashiKumar - Were you able to see the navigate onShellClick on any iOS device with the Shell Header in place?

Comment: I only able to reproduce this issue on android device because I only code for android environment only. Anyhow I reported this issue on github last time which got fixed recently. Can follow this link: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9765

Answer (score 0):

I organized each `ShellContent` in a single `FlyoutItem`.  On my end, the navigation works fine. Also you need to set the `Route` property.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-routes

Please see the example below:

XAML

```xml
<!-- Flyout Items -->
    <FlyoutItem
        Title="{x:Static localization:Strings.Status}"
        >
        <FlyoutItem.Icon>
            <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIcons}"
                Glyph="{StaticResource MaterialDesign_ProgressCheck}"
                Color="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
                Size="{StaticResource DefaultIconSize}"
                />
        </FlyoutItem.Icon>
        <!-- Status -->
        <ShellContent 
            Title="{x:Static localization:Strings.Status}" 
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:KlipperStatePage}"
            Route="KlipperStatePage"
            />
    </FlyoutItem>

<FlyoutItem
        Title="{x:Static localization:Strings.ControlPanel}" 
        >
        <FlyoutItem.Icon>
            <FontImageSource
                FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignIcons}"
                Glyph="{StaticResource MaterialDesign_TuneVertical}"
                Color="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
                Size="{StaticResource DefaultIconSize}"
                />
        </FlyoutItem.Icon>
        <ShellContent
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SingleControlPanelPage}"
            Route="SingleControlPanelPage"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsLightVersion,Converter={StaticResource BooleanReverseVisibilityConverter}}"
            >
        </ShellContent>
    </FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: I have updated the code as the suggestion but it's still not fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample to test and met the same problem. It seems the FlyoutItem's special behavior in the maui. If you want to go to the root page instead of the last page navigated on the content page when user click the FlyoutItem, you can try the following code.

In the AppShell.xaml:

```
        <ShellContent 
            Title="Change Working Location" 
            Icon="navigation.png" 
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:LocationPage}"
            Route="LocationPage"/>
        <ShellContent 
            Title="Main Menu"
            Icon="home_grey.png" 
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:AboutPage}" 
            Route="AboutPage"/>
```

In the clicked event:

```
 public async void List_Tapped()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(AboutPage)}");
    }
```